# Subclassing multiprocessing.queue.Queue: attributes set by parent not available to child?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle

I'm using the multiprocessing library with python 3.7 with a parent process that talks to a child process via a queue. I can use a multiprocessing.queue.Queue just fine, but when I subclass to add some extra features to the queue, they get set in the parent just fine but seem to be missing when accessed by the child. Any idea how I can get the attributes to persist in the child?

```
import sys
import time
import multiprocessing
import multiprocessing.queues

# Subclass multiprocessing.queue.Queue to add some useful features
class q_class(multiprocessing.queues.Queue):
    def __init__(self):
        self.report_bottlenecks = False
        self.bottleneck_time = 1.0 #in seconds
        super(q_class, self).__init__(ctx=multiprocessing.get_context())
    def put(self,header,payload=None):
        message = {}
        message['header'] = header
        message['payload'] = payload
        message['put_time'] = time.time()
        super(q_class, self).put(message)
    def get(self):
        message = super(q_class, self).get()
        message['get_time'] = time.time()
        message['queue_time'] = message['get_time'] - message['put_time']
        if self.report_bottlenecks:
            if message['queue_time']>self.bottleneck_time:
                self.debug.print('Queue bottleneck: '+str(int(message['queue_time']))+' seconds.')
        return(message)

def function_for_child_to_run(the_q):
    print('Child process started')
    print(the_q.report_bottlenecks) #currently causes an AttributeError: 'q_class' object has no attribute 'report_bottlenecks'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.set_start_method('forkserver')
    my_q = q_class()
    print(my_q.report_bottlenecks) #should print "False"
    process = multiprocessing.Process( target=function_for_child_to_run , args=(my_q,) )
    process.start()
    time.sleep(2) #give the child time to start & print
    process.join()
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For use with forkserver, your queue has to be pickled. `multiprocessing.queues.Queue` defines `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` methods for pickling and unpickling the instance attributes. When you add your attributes to the subclassed Queue, you have to expand these two methods with your custom attributes or they will get lost.

Add this to your code:

```
from multiprocessing import context
...
class QClass(multiprocessing.queues.Queue):     
    ...
    def __getstate__(self):
        context.assert_spawning(self)
        return (self._ignore_epipe, self._maxsize, self._reader, self._writer,
                self._rlock, self._wlock, self._sem, self._opid,
                self.report_bottlenecks, self.bottleneck_time)  # <---

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        (self._ignore_epipe, self._maxsize, self._reader, self._writer,
         self._rlock, self._wlock, self._sem, self._opid,
         self.report_bottlenecks, self.bottleneck_time) = state  # <---
        self._after_fork()
```